# Puedo generar una app .ipa sin una mac o sin virtualizar una mac?

Tags: visual-studio, ionic, xcode, xamarin

mas que un problema tengo una consulta... Tengo una aplicacion web y quiero que se vea en una web view... con android no tengo problemas... pero para ios si... pues no tengo una mac y tampoco el dinero para comprarme uno... en fin.. mi cunsulta es.. Puedo generar la app .ipa desde una pc windows o linux sin tener que virtualizar una mac? lei que con visual studio y xamarin uno lo puede emular pero hasta ahi... yo quiero saber si puedo generar el .ipa directamente desde linux o windows...

Comment: Lamentablemente para generar cualquier aplicación es necesario firmarla desde una mac, aunque, puedes rentar una a través de internet y conectarte [remotamente desde visual studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/).

Comment: como seria eso de rentar?

Answer (score 1):

Es requisito tener una Mac para poder generar el .ipa por los sdks y el certificado.